# There exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathrm{Im} f^{n} + \mathrm{Ker} f^{n} = M$ if $M$ satisfies DCC

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $M$ be an $R$-module, and let $f$ be an $R$-automorphism on $M$. Prove that if $M$ satisfies the [descending chain condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition), then there exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\operatorname{Im} f^{n} + \operatorname{Ker} f^{n} = M$.

Comment: Automorphism is in particular isomorphism this is trivial because $kerf=0$. I think u meant endomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $ \operatorname{im}(f) \supseteq \operatorname{im}(f^2) \supseteq \operatorname{im}(f^3) \supseteq \cdots$ so by the DCC, there is an integer $n$ such that $\operatorname{im}(f^n)=\operatorname{im}(f^{2n}).$ Let $m\in M.$ Since $\operatorname{im}(f^n)=\operatorname{im}(f^{2n}),$ there is some $t\in M$ such that $f^n(m)=f^{2n}(t).$ Write $m=(m-f^n(t)) + f^n(t)$ and we're done.

Comment: May you make your hint more precise? I need more details on the last sentence you wrote.

Comment: The second term is $f^n(t),$ which is inside $\operatorname{im}(f^n).$ The first term is $m-f^n(t),$ which you can check is inside $\ker (f^n).$

Comment: @user110834: A similar question for you : Let $M$ be a $R$-module and $f$ be a $R$-automorphism on $M$. Prove that if $M$ satisfies ACC condition then there exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $Imf^{n}\cap Kerf^{n}=M$

Comment: How should we do with this problem?

Comment: chuyenvien94's problem is incorrect. The conclusion should be that the intersection is $0,$ not $M.$

Comment: @Ragib Zaman : Can you explain more precise?