# If $M$ satisfies ACC, do we have a similar result?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $f$ an $R$-endomorphism on $M$. If $M$ satisfies [DCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition) then  [There exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $Imf^{n}+Kerf^{n}=M$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580511/there-exist-n-in-mathbbn-such-that-imfnkerfn-m).

> If $M$ satisfies ACC, do we have a similar result?

Comment: I can't see. Can you give me the link?

Comment: Can you prove it more precise? The author of the book only told "similarly"